# Nginx reverse proxy to SSL websockets in R Shiny

Tags: r, nginx, shiny

I have Nginx configured as a reverse proxy that will allow me to present local services without SSL/authentication to the network as services with SSL/authentication. [The configuration](https://gist.github.com/sambrightman/47606b400c90ed5651b22c980a5e7410) looks a lot like examples I see on Stack Overflow and in the Nginx documentation.

This seems to work really well in basic cases. However, I am trying to run [R Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) behind it which appears to somehow use websockets to detect when the server has gone away. Without the proxy, the page never detects the server going away unless it really does (page gets a grey overlay). With the proxy, the page goes grey after `proxy_read_timeout`. I do not want to set an arbitrarily high value as it would obviously not fix websockets in general. The configuration section seems to [match examples](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) I see for how to get websockets working:

```
location /latencies/ {
    auth_request /auth-proxy;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

I've also tried adding the `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `proxy_buffering off` settings [described in the Shiny documentation](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213733868-Running-Shiny-Server-with-a-Proxy).

I do not see errors in either the Chrome or Firefox developer tools. I do not even see network requests going out or coming in, so not even 100% sure what causes this. [I do see code in Shiny](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/cad20a0bfea9d02dc9f163f028a0c498462fdd90/srcjs/shinyapp.js#L212) that suggests websockets are being used for liveness testing.

(I'm aware of R Shiny Server and ShinyProxy, which might or might not help. I want to avoid adding more moving parts/learning those as well if possible).